# Connecting to 'unix"//var/run/charon.ctl' failed: connection refused

Tags: linux, debian, udev, ipsec, yubikey

I have tried to find some answers on this and other sites trying to find out the problem, but my attempts failed. The rule is very simple: I want to establish my Ipsec tunnel when my Yubikey is plugged.

- My rule is in the file `/etc/udev/rules.d/local.rules`

In which the script goes as:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="input", ACTION=="add", ENV{ID_MODEL}=="Yubikey_4_OTP+U2F+CCID" , RUN+="/usr/local/bin/Yubikey.sh"
```

Then the script `/usr/local/bin/Yubikey.sh` contains:

```
#!/bin/sh
ipsec restart 
if (ipsec status | grep none);then
     ipsec up connection
fi
```

This invokes the script when any input device is plugged, and then the script should restart ipsec and initiate the tunnel if there was not a tunnel initiated before. However, the tunnel doesn't initiate as I get the following error when I run `ipsec status` command:

```
connecting to 'unix:///var/run/charon.ctl' failed: Connection refused
failed to connect to stroke socket 'unix"//var/run/charon.ctl'
```

Comment: Ubikey and IPsec, good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after researching more, I found out that the problem in `/usr/local/bin/Yubikey.sh` script which calls `ipsec` as a service which caused the stroke socket `charon.ctl` to fail. 
Instead, I had to change it to:

```
#!/bin/sh
service strongswan restart
```

So, I had to use strongswan instead of ipsec as in the recent distributions , ipsec command has been renamed to [strongswan](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/IpsecCommand).

Comment: While some distributions (e.g. CentOS/Fedora) rename the `ipsec` script to `strongswan` that is not related to the `service` utility and the services it can control (usually System V init scripts, but depends on the system). The latter may be called `strongswan` while the script is still named `ipsec` and vice-versa. And the script's or service's name has nothing to do with the reason you are not able to access the socket.

Comment: ok, thanks for the clarification. Could you add your edit to this answer then? 
Because this answer works for me so far and I have no further explanation to what is happening exactly.

Answer (score 1):

By default only root is allowed to access that socket (and others created by strongSwan). There are [options to change that](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/ReducedPrivileges). For instance, with *charon.group* in [strongswan.conf](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/Strongswanconf) users that are members of the configured group are also allowed to access the socket. There might also be some kernel level security module (e.g. AppArmor) on your system that could prevent access to the socket (check the system log for entries and maybe adapt the policies accordingly).

Instead of using the deprecated ipsec/starter/stroke you might want to consider switching to [VICI](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/Vici)/[swanctl](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/swanctl).

Comment: thanks for your answer. I just the question and I found out `charon.ctl ` accepts only `service strongswan restart` instead of `ipsec restart` command. And yes, as you mentioned, `ipsec/starter/stroke` is deprecated, that is why I thought I could `service strongswan` instead.